# clojure lazy-seq performance optimization

Tags: performance, clojure, lazy-sequences

I'm fairly new to Clojure and I have some code that I am trying to optimise. I want to compute concurrance-counts. 
The main function is *compute-space* and the output is a nested map of the type

```
{"w1" {"w11" 10, "w12" 31, ...}
 "w2" {"w21" 14, "w22" 1,  ...}
 ... 
 }
```

meaning that "w1" cooccurs with "w11" 10 times, etc...

It takes a coll of documents (sentences) and a coll of target words, it iterates over both and finally applies the *context-fn* such as *sliding-window* to extract context-words. More concretely I am passing a closure over *sliding-window*

```
(compute-space docs (fn [target doc] (sliding-window target doc 5)) targets)
```

I've been testing it with around 50 million words (~ 3 million sentences) and ca. 20,000 targets. This version would take more than a day to complete. I also wrote a *pmap* parallel function (*pcompute-space*) that would reduce computing time to around 10 hours, but I still I feel it should be faster. I don't have other code to compare, but my intuition says it should be faster.

```
(defn compute-space 
  ([docs context-fn targets]
    (let [space (atom {})]
      (doseq [doc docs
              target targets]
        (when-let [contexts (context-fn target doc)]
          (doseq [w contexts]
            (if (get-in @space [target w])
              (swap! space update-in [target w] (partial inc))
              (swap! space assoc-in  [target w] 1)))))
     @space)))

(defn sliding-window
  [target s n]
  (loop [todo s seen [] acc []]
    (let [curr (first todo)]
      (cond (= curr target) (recur (rest todo) (cons curr seen) (concat acc (take n seen) (take n (rest todo))))
            (empty? todo) acc
            :else (recur (rest todo) (cons curr seen) acc)))))


(defn pcompute-space
  [docs step context-fn targets]
  (reduce
     #(deep-merge-with + %1 %2)
      (pmap
        (fn [chunk]
          (do (tick))
          (compute-space chunk context-fn targets))
        (partition-all step docs)))
```

I profiled the application with *jvisualvm* and I found out that clojure.lang.Cons, clojure.lang.ChunkedCons and clojure.lang.ArrayChunk are dominating the process quite excessively (see picture). This surely has to do with the fact that I am using this double *doseq* loop, (previous experiments showed that this way was faster than using map, reduce and the like, although I was using *time* for benchmarking the functions).
I'd very thankful for any insights you could provide me, and suggestions for refactor the code and make it run faster. I guess *reducers* could be of some help here, but I'm not sure as to how and/or why.

[image: jvisualvm memory profile]

**SPECS**

MacPro 2010 2,4 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo 4 GB RAM

Clojure 1.6.0

Java 1.7.0_51 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM

[Test data](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/emanjavacas/lexvar/master/lexvar_at_test.filt)

[GithubGist with the entire code](https://gist.github.com/emanjavacas/d8672fa88016a7a3e81a)

Comment: sorry! I did some refactoring

Comment: Not related to optimization, but `(partial inc)` is essentially the same as `inc`.

Comment: `sliding-window` takes three arguments, but only two are passed to `context-fn`.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance, thanks for the observation. In the case of `context-fn` it is actually a closure what is passed to `compute-space`. (fn [target sent] (sliding-window target sent 5)) for instance. I will edit the question to make this clear

Answer (score 4):

Test data was:

- A lazy seq of 42 strings (targets)
- A lazy seq of 105,040 lazy sets. (Documents)
- Each lazy seq within Documents was a lazy sequence of strings. The total number of strings contained in documents was 1,146,190.

Quite a bit smaller than your work load. [Criterium](http://hugoduncan.org/criterium/) was used to collect timing. Criterium computes an expression multiple times, first warming up the JIT and then to collect average data.

With my test data, and your code, `compute-space` took 22 seconds:

```
WARNING: JVM argument TieredStopAtLevel=1 is active, and may lead to unexpected results as JIT C2 compiler may not be active. See http://www.slideshare.net/CharlesNutter/javaone-2012-jvm-jit-for-dummies.
Evaluation count : 60 in 60 samples of 1 calls.
             Execution time mean : 21.989189 sec
    Execution time std-deviation : 471.199127 ms
   Execution time lower quantile : 21.540155 sec ( 2.5%)
   Execution time upper quantile : 23.226352 sec (97.5%)
                   Overhead used : 13.353852 ns

Found 2 outliers in 60 samples (3.3333 %)
    low-severe   2 (3.3333 %)
 Variance from outliers : 9.4329 % Variance is slightly inflated by outliers
```

**First optimization** *Updated to use `frequencies` to go from vector of words to map of words and counts of their occurrences.*

To help me understand the structure of the computation I wrote a separate function that takes a collection of documents, `context-fn` and a single target, and returns the map of context words to counts. The inner map for one target of what is returned by `compute-space`. Wrote this using built in Clojure functions, instead of updating counts.

```
(defn compute-context-map-f [documents context-fn target]
  (frequencies (mapcat #(context-fn target %) documents)))
```

With `compute-context-map-f` written `compute-space`, named `compute-space-f here`, is fairly short:

```
(defn compute-space-f [docs context-fn targets]
  (into {} (map #(vector % (compute-context-map-f docs context-fn %)) targets)))
```

Timing, with the same data as above is 65% of original version:

```
WARNING: JVM argument TieredStopAtLevel=1 is active, and may lead to unexpected results as JIT C2 compiler may not be active. See http://www.slideshare.net/CharlesNutter/javaone-2012-jvm-jit-for-dummies.
Evaluation count : 60 in 60 samples of 1 calls.
             Execution time mean : 14.274344 sec
    Execution time std-deviation : 345.240183 ms
   Execution time lower quantile : 13.981537 sec ( 2.5%)
   Execution time upper quantile : 15.088521 sec (97.5%)
                   Overhead used : 13.353852 ns

Found 3 outliers in 60 samples (5.0000 %)
    low-severe   1 (1.6667 %)
    low-mild     2 (3.3333 %)
 Variance from outliers : 12.5419 % Variance is moderately inflated by outliers
```

**Parallelize first optimization**

I chose to chunk by target instead of document, so that merging the maps together would not require modifying the `{context-word count, ...}` maps for a target.

```
(defn pcompute-space-f [docs step context-fn targets]
  (into {} (pmap #(compute-space-f docs context-fn %) (partition-all step targets))))
```

Timing, with the same data as above is 16% of original version:

```
user> (criterium.core/bench (pcompute-space-f documents 4 #(sliding-window %1 %2 5) keywords))
WARNING: JVM argument TieredStopAtLevel=1 is active, and may lead to unexpected results as JIT C2 compiler may not be active. See http://www.slideshare.net/CharlesNutter/javaone-2012-jvm-jit-for-dummies.
Evaluation count : 60 in 60 samples of 1 calls.
             Execution time mean : 3.623018 sec
    Execution time std-deviation : 83.780996 ms
   Execution time lower quantile : 3.486419 sec ( 2.5%)
   Execution time upper quantile : 3.788714 sec (97.5%)
                   Overhead used : 13.353852 ns

Found 1 outliers in 60 samples (1.6667 %)
    low-severe   1 (1.6667 %)
 Variance from outliers : 11.0038 % Variance is moderately inflated by outliers
```

**Specifications**

- Mac Pro 2009 2.66 GHz Quad-Core Intel Xeon, 48 GB RAM.
- Clojure 1.6.0.
- Java 1.8.0_40 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM.

**TBD**

Further optimizations.

Describe the test data.

Comment: First of all thanks for your code and help! After trying it on my computer I am a bit puzzled though because I got contradictory results. I've added my specs a github gist with the entire involved code (i/o function etc..), criterium results and a link to the test file I'm using. Any insights as to why this divergence?

Comment: @emanjavacas Interesting. I do not know if I will have time to look at it though.

Comment: Since I've had no response from OP, could I ask you to verify [my work](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29561227/1562315)?

Comment: @Thumbnail, you have some good ideas there, that are backed up by your own timings. I don't have time for this problem to verify or critique your work. Sorry.

Comment: I got round to using Criterium. Testing all the targets at once does work a huge improvement, but moving to transients actually slows things down! Still no word from OP.

Answer (score 1):

**Analysis of the `compute-space` algorithm in the question**

The cost of scanning the sentences - looking for targets -

- is proportional to the total number of words
- is proportional to the number of targets, but
- is more of less independent of the number of sentences that the words are divided into.

The cost of dealing with the targets

- is proportional to the target hit rate,
- is proportional to the number of distinct words in its context.

**Major improvement**

The `context-fn` scans a sentence looking for a target. *If there are ten-thousand targets, it scans the sentence ten-thousand times*.

Far better scan the sentence *once*, looking for *all* the targets. If we keep the targets as a (hash) set, we can test whether a word is a target in more or less constant time, *no matter how many targets there are*.

**Possible improvement**

The `sliding-windows` function generates contexts by passing each word from hand to hand - from `todo` to `seen`. It is *probably* quicker to pour the words into a vector, then return the contexts as `subvec`s.

However it is done, a simple way to organise generating the contexts is to have the `context-fn` return the *sequence of contexts* corresponding to the sequence of words. A function that does this for `sliding-windows` is

```
(defn sliding-windows [w s]
  (let [v (vec s), n (count v)
        window (fn [i] (lazy-cat (subvec v (max (- i w) 0) i)
                                 (subvec v (inc i) (min (inc (+ i w)) n))))]
    (map window (range n))))
```

We can now define the `compute-space` function in terms of the new kind of `contexts-fn` as follows:

```
(defn compute-space [docs contexts-fn target?]
  (letfn [(stuff [s] (->> (map vector s (contexts-fn s))
                          (filter (comp target? first))))]
    (reduce
     (fn [a [k m]] (assoc a k (merge-with + (a k) (frequencies m))))
     {}
     (mapcat stuff docs))))
```

The code pivots on `stuff`:

- We develop `stuff` as a sequence of `[target context-sequence]` pairs.
- We then merge each pair into the aggregate, adding the corresponding neighbour counts for each target occurrence.

**Results**

This algorithm is about 500 times faster than that in the question: what the code in the question accomplishes in a day and a half, this should perform in about a minute.

Given

- a vocabulary of 100,000 words,
- one sentence of 100,000 words, and
- 10,000 targets

this code constructs the context map in 100 msec.

For a sentence a tenth as long - 10,000 words - the code in the question takes 5 sec.

This is using (long) integers rather than strings as "words". So the work of assembling the strings with their hash values will dilute the improvement somewhat.

**Note**

I took the original version of this answer down because

- there was transcription error in the code;
- the performance claims were not accurate.

With accurate tests - conducted by Criterium - the version that uses transient maps turns out to be a little slower, so has been omitted.

Comment: sorry I wasn't notified of your answer. Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I won't have time to test your suggestions in the short time but they do sound interesting. Another thing that I'd like to try is to move into the reducers framework.

Comment: @emanjavacas Moving to the reducers/transducers framework will produce a constant factor improvement - I'd guess 2 to 5, though it may be more. The answer above produces an improvement proportional to the number of targets: in your case, roughly a factor of 10K.